# Next js api ip address return server ip not client ip

Tags: next.js

I'm using a Next js application, I'm trying to get the IP address and geolocation of the client user, but I got the id address of the `vercel` server that I deployed on.

I tried `middleware`:

```
import { NextFetchEvent, NextRequest, NextResponse } from 'next/server';

export async function middleware(request: NextRequest, _next: NextFetchEvent) {
    const { nextUrl: url, geo } = request
    const country = geo?.country

    // Clone the request headers and set a new header `x-hello-from-middleware1`
    const requestHeaders = new Headers(request.headers)
    requestHeaders.set('country', country||'EG')
    
    // You can also set request headers in NextResponse.rewrite
    const response = NextResponse.next({
        request: {
            // New request headers
            headers: requestHeaders,
        },
    })
    
    return response
}
```

then, when using `country` from header in `api` directory:

```
export default async (req:MyRequest, res:NextApiResponse) => {
   if (req.method === 'GET') {
      const country= req.headers.country;
   }
}
```

I got server's country !!

I also tried:

```
export default async (req:MyRequest, res:NextApiResponse) => {
   if (req.method === 'GET') {
      const forwarded = req.headers['x-forwarded-for'];
      const ip = typeof forwarded === 'string' ? forwarded.split(/, /)[0] : req.socket.remoteAddress;
   }
}
```

But it's the same result! the ip of the hosting server.

Why?! and what's the solution?

Answer (score 2):

[from here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Forwarded-For)

> When a client connects directly to a server, the client's IP address
> is sent to the server (and is often written to server access logs).
> But if a client connection passes through any forward or reverse
> proxies, the server only sees the final proxy's IP address, which is
> often of little use. That's especially true if the final proxy is a
> load balancer which is part of the same installation as the server.

I think the problem is either you are using proxy or vercel is using a load balancer. `NextRequest` has `ip` method. try to use

```
const ip = req.ip ?? "127.0.0.1";
```

Comment: Thank you, I knew why, but ` req.ip` still return server's ip address